# React renders array elements in wrong order although keys are unique

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, rendering

I have a component ScoreTable, which displays props data as html table. The problem is, that react renders some rows in wrong order. Keys are unique and static. I'm using useEffect to print data whenever it change. The code, console output and rendered table are below.

**Code:**

```
interface Props {
  title: string;
  data?: ScoreboardT | null;
  keys?: string[];
  variant?: string;
}

export const ScoreTable: React.FC<Props> = ({
  data,
  title,
  keys = [
    'No.',
    'Name',
    'Played',
    'Won',
    'Tied',
    'Lost',
    'GF',
    'GA',
    'GD',
    'Points'
  ],
  variant = 'normal'
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('new data', data);
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <Table striped bordered variant={variant}>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colSpan={12} className='text-center'>
            {title}
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          {keys.map((key, index) => (
            <th key={index}>{key}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {data &&
          data.map((row, index) => (
            <tr key={row.id}>
              <td>{index + 1}</td>
              <th>
                <Badge>{row.in_group_id}</Badge>
                {row.name}
              </th>
              <td>{row.played_matches}</td>
              <td>{row.won_matches}</td>
              <td>{row.tied_matches}</td>
              <td>{row.lost_matches}</td>
              <td>{row.scored_goals}</td>
              <td>{row.lost_goals}</td>
              <td>{row.goals_difference}</td>
              <th>{row.points}</th>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  );
};
```

**Console output**

```
new data: null
new data: [
  {
    "id": "5",
    "in_group_id": "A5",
    "group_name": "A",
    "name": "Polonia Kraków 2",
    "tourney_id": 1,
    "scored_goals": "23",
    "lost_goals": "7",
    "points": "17",
    "won_matches": "5",
    "tied_matches": "2",
    "lost_matches": "0",
    "played_matches": "7",
    "goals_difference": "16"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "in_group_id": "A2",
    "group_name": "A",
    "name": "Progress Angdrychów",
    "tourney_id": 1,
    "scored_goals": "21",
    "lost_goals": "5",
    "points": "17",
    "won_matches": "5",
    "tied_matches": "2",
    "lost_matches": "0",
    "played_matches": "7",
    "goals_difference": "16"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "in_group_id": "A8",
    "group_name": "A",
    "name": "AP Wieliczka",
    "tourney_id": 1,
    "scored_goals": "9",
    "lost_goals": "9",
    "points": "10",
    "won_matches": "3",
    "tied_matches": "1",
    "lost_matches": "3",
    "played_matches": "7",
    "goals_difference": "0"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "in_group_id": "A1",
    "group_name": "A",
    "name": "Sandecja Nowy Sącz",
    "tourney_id": 1,
    "scored_goals": "12",
    "lost_goals": "14",
    "points": "9",
    "won_matches": "2",
    "tied_matches": "3",
    "lost_matches": "2",
    "played_matches": "7",
    "goals_difference": "-2"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "in_group_id": "A7",
    "group_name": "A",
    "name": "Futbol Brzączowice",
    "tourney_id": 1,
    "scored_goals": "12",
    "lost_goals": "13",
    "points": "9",
    "won_matches": "3",
    "tied_matches": "0",
    "lost_matches": "4",
    "played_matches": "7",
    "goals_difference": "-1"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "in_group_id": "A4",
    "group_name": "A",
    "name": "Clepardia Kraków",
    "tourney_id": 1,
    "scored_goals": "16",
    "lost_goals": "12",
    "points": "9",
    "won_matches": "2",
    "tied_matches": "3",
    "lost_matches": "2",
    "played_matches": "7",
    "goals_difference": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "in_group_id": "A6",
    "group_name": "A",
    "name": "Orliki Myślenice",
    "tourney_id": 1,
    "scored_goals": "3",
    "lost_goals": "23",
    "points": "4",
    "won_matches": "1",
    "tied_matches": "1",
    "lost_matches": "5",
    "played_matches": "7",
    "goals_difference": "-20"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "in_group_id": "A3",
    "group_name": "A",
    "name": "AS Progres Kraków",
    "tourney_id": 1,
    "scored_goals": "5",
    "lost_goals": "18",
    "points": "2",
    "won_matches": "0",
    "tied_matches": "2",
    "lost_matches": "5",
    "played_matches": "7",
    "goals_difference": "-13"
  }
]
```

**Table**
[rendered table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhZof.png)

My question is: How can I make React render those elements in the same order as the array is logged in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort your array before mapping it:

JS Native:

```
 <tbody>
    {data &&
      data
        .sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id) // <-- this is the line to be added
        .map((row, index) => (
        <tr key={row.id}>
          <td>{index + 1}</td>
          <th>
            <Badge>{row.in_group_id}</Badge>
            {row.name}
          </th>
          <td>{row.played_matches}</td>
          <td>{row.won_matches}</td>
          <td>{row.tied_matches}</td>
          <td>{row.lost_matches}</td>
          <td>{row.scored_goals}</td>
          <td>{row.lost_goals}</td>
          <td>{row.goals_difference}</td>
          <th>{row.points}</th>
        </tr>
      ))}
  </tbody>
```

Lodash:

```
 <tbody>
    {data &&
      _.sortBy(data, 'id')
        .map((row, index) => (
```

Comment: I want to render elements in the same order as they are in array right now. Sorting is not an option. If you look on console output and rendered table, you will see a difference in how they are ordered and that's my problem.